# Can't read field content from lucene index

Tags: java, indexing, lucene

So I have an index that is created by lucene (Java).
I am trying to search the index as following

```
TopDocs result = searcher.search(query, maxResults);
for (ScoreDoc scoreDoc : result.scoreDocs) {
    Document doc = searcher.doc(scoreDoc.doc);
    LogService.logger().warning("Title| " + doc.get("title"));
    LogService.logger().warning("URL| " + doc.get("url"));
```

The code prints the url field but prints `null` for the title field.

My first guess was that there might be an issue with the field name or the content is actually null.

However I double checked with Lucene [Luke](https://github.com/DmitryKey/luke) (GUI-based inspection tool) and the field name seems to be OK and the content is definitely not `null`.

I am not sure what could be the reason for that .. any suggestions ?

**P.S:** Both indexing and searching were performed using the same lucene version (6.2.1)

Comment: Are you specifying any list of fields in Search request?

Comment: @DarshanMehta not at all

Comment: Could you show has the relevant parts of the indexing code?

Answer (score 3):

Well, you haven't provided enough information to be sure, but I'd bet that field isn't stored. If you are using a `TextField`, and using a `Reader` or `TokenStream` as the source, for instance, the field will not be stored, and will be searchable, but you will not be able to retrieve it.

You can make a TextField stored like:

```
Field titleField = new TextField("title", "The Sun Also Rises", Field.Store.YES);
```